# how to identify the id of an HTML element having a certain class

Tags: jquery

I've my HTML codes as

```
<li><button id="1" class="vote btn" type="button" /></li>
<li><button id="2" class="voteUp btn" type="button" /></li>  // Only button with class= voteUp
<li><button id="3" class="vote btn" type="button" /></li>
<li><button id="4" class="vote btn" type="button" /></li>
.
.
.
<li><button id="x" class="vote btn" type="button" /></li>
```

Now through jquery, when I click any of these buttons, I want to find out the id of the button who has got the class 'voteUp'. (There will be only one button having this class).

How can I find it?? I'm trying to figure it out using `.hasClass()` but not successful till now. Kindly help.

UPDATE:

Actual HTML & PHP codes

```
<li class="box">
    <div class="temLine">This is the fifth line</div>
    <div class="pushUp"><input id="line5" class="voteUpBtn vote" name="voteUp" type="button" /></div>
     <div class="userName clear">- by ptamzz</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

Above code will be looped using PHP and a list will be generated. Like I said, one of the button (input here) will have a 'voteUp' class while all others have 'vote' class.

Comment: Duh, because `.hasClass()` checks classes, not IDs?

Comment: FYI, it isn't valid in HTML4 to have an ID starting with a number.

Comment: @boltClock Well, I was trying to find the button which has got the class and then though I could determine the id... Instead of a 'duh' I'd have appreciated more if you knew the answer and had provided it.. :)

Comment: @patrick thanks for the info.. in my real codes, the id is not starting with a number.. it's something like "line1".. I just typed it short here..

Comment: Thank you for updating your question - it's always better to show your actual markup. Since this really has nothing to do with PHP, however, it would be _even more useful_ to show the HTML that the client sees. _That_ is what the JavaScript acts on; _that_ is what matters.

Comment: Just another note: In general, only include as much code as necessary in a question. But if the question is about accessing elements in a certain structure, then the exact structure *is* needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're binding the click handler on the `<button>`s or on the `<li>`s, then inside of your click handler, this will get you the ID of the button with class `voteUp`:

```
var buttonID = $(this).closest('ul').find('li > div > button.voteUp').attr('id');
```

**Edited** to reflect the actual markup the OP's working with.

Comment: +1 Good demonstration of how `.closest()` can overcome the fragility of targeting ancestors at a specific level.

Comment: @patrick: thanks, but it looks like I still need to edit the code a bit in light of the OP's edit :)

Comment: I just changed the 'button' to 'input' since in my actual markup I'm using 'input'.. although my mistake, first time I posted it as 'button'.. It's working now. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, the selector restores the fragility avoided with `.closest()`. I'd probably just do `.find('button.voteUp')` to make it more resilient against structural changes.

Comment: @ptamzz: you're welcome. See what I mean about posting your **actual markup**?

Comment: Btw. although it reflects the structure, you gain nothing from `li > div > input.voteUp`, as jQuery evaluates the selector from the right. I think it is save to assume that there are no other `input.voteUp` elements outside of `li` s or `div` s, hence, just using `input.voteUp` is sufficient (and potentially faster). Also note that the updated code uses `input` instead of `button` (and you already got +1 from me anyway ;))

Answer (score 7):

Inside the click handler:

```
var id = $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('.voteUp').attr('id');
```

this will check *all other buttons*. To find out whether the *current* button is the one with class `voteUp`, you can simple use `$(this).hasClass('voteUp')` (you could also create one expression to check all buttons, but why do an unnecessary (maybe expensive) lookup?).

So in summary, something like:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var id;
    if($(this).hasClass('voteUp')) {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
    }
    else {
        id = $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('.voteUp').attr('id');
    }
});
```

**Update:**

For a detailed explanation of what the methods do, have a look at http://api.jquery.com

In short:

- `.parent()` will get the parent element
- `.siblings('li')` will select all the siblings of the element that are a `<li>` element (siblings are all the other elements that are at the same level as the element (thus having the same parent))
- `.children('.voteUp')` will select the children (direct descendants) with class `voteUp` of an element.
- `.attr('id')` returns the value of the `id` attribute.

You say your buttons are actually wrapped in another `div`. Then instead of using `.parent()` and `.children()`, the call should look like this:

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('.voteUp').attr('id');
```

where

- `.closest()` will return the closest ancestor that matches the selector
- `.find()` will return *any* descendant that matches the given selector

Comment: Can you please explain the main part id = $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('.voteUp').attr('id'); a little bit. I'm new with this.. it's not working with me, maybe because actually with my codes the button is wrapped inside a div in my actual codes..

Comment: @ptamzz: the difference in the HTML structure is exactly why Felix's code does not work. Please update your question with the _actual_ HTML. If you want specific information about what each function does, you can read the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: @Felix: you've got to be careful with the `.closest(...).siblings(...)` bit, because that omits the `<li>` (etc.) that `this` is in. You either need to `.add()` the result of `.closest()` and `.siblings()`, or perform a special-case check (as your original code did) for `$(this).hasClass(...)`. I say this more for the OP's benefit than yours, of course!

Comment: +1 for the originally correct answer. -1 for not being psychic. +1 for making up for not being psychic.  ;o)

Comment: @patrick: It's weekend, psychic is only for weekdays ;) @Matt: The updated selector is only meant as a replacement for the one used in the `else` clause in my original code, but thanks for pointing that out.